# How to export tkinter.treeview() data to json file in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I'm working on a tkinter program where I store some data in a json file and load that data into a treeview object (tkinter widget). Thats working all fine. I can update the fields in the treeview also just fine. But how do I save that data and override my json file? I keep hitting the wall on this. Heres my not working code (I know the string is not correct, it's just gorillacode):

```
data = {}
        data['people'] = []
        for row_id in my_tree.get_children():
            row = my_tree.item(row_id)["values"]
            string = "name": "+row[0]+", "birthdate": "+row[1]+"
            data['people'].append({string})
        with open('birthdays.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
```

The output in the json file have to end up looking like this:

```
{"people": [{"name": "Vincent", "birthdate": "08/01/2011"}, {"name": "Josephine", "birthdate": "08/01/2011"}, {"name": "Athena", "birthdate": "24/01/2012"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was easier to do a .write(string)
I had some backslashes in the file that i removed before with .replace().
ended up working fine for me.